# VIM colors downloader in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, network-file-transfer

Recently, I wanted to change my vim colors to something new. So I went to the `vim colors` website and then I decided that I wanted to download ALL the colors.

So I wrote this simple Python script that will download all the files from: [Vim Colors](http://vimcolors.com/?page=1)

I'm still learning Python and it would be amazing to get some feedback / suggestions if possible.

```
import os
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Spider:
    def __init__(self, total_pages=40):
        self.base_url = "http://vimcolors.com/?page="
        self.total_pages = total_pages
        self.download_dir = 'colors/'
        # If we don't have the download directory
        if not os.path.isdir(self.download_dir):
            print(self.download_dir, 'does not exist, trying to create it...')
            # create it...
            os.mkdir(self.download_dir)

    def download(self, name, url):
        # If we have already downloaded this file, just skip
        if os.path.isfile(self.download_dir + name):
            print('File:', name, 'already exists; skipping.')
            return

        try:
            # Get the response
            response = requests.get(url)
            # If response is 404 (Not Found), just exit
            if response.status_code == 404:
                raise Exception('File not found')
            # Create the file
            with open(self.download_dir + name, 'wb') as file_path:
                # Write content to the file
                file_path.write(response.content)
                # Confirm the download
                print('Downloaded', name)
        except:
            # This is a very generic error, perhaps I'll change it sometime :)
            print('Could not download the file', name)
            pass

    def crawl(self):
        def repo_formatter(scheme):
            return scheme['github_repo']['address'].replace('github.com', 'raw.githubusercontent.com') \
                   + '/master/colors/' + scheme['name'] + '.vim'

        # Loop over all the pages
        for page in range(self.total_pages):
            page_source = requests.get(self.base_url + str(page + 1))
            plain_text = page_source.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')

            # Get the data
            json_data = json.loads(soup.find('div', {'id': 'data'}).attrs['data-colorschemes'])

            # Download the files
            for data in json_data['colorschemes']:
                self.download(data['name'] + '.vim', repo_formatter(data))


colors_spider = Spider()
colors_spider.crawl()
```

Comment: Welcome to code review, I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I left the original in there. I did not delete the one I had before, but that's fine. :) thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very nice code in general! Here are a few points, though:

Think about using `os.makedirs` instead of `os.mkdir`. The former allows creating nested directories (so `os.makedirs("~/long/new/path")` will create all other folders in betweetn as well, if needed).

You should never have a bare `except`. This prevents you to e.g. CTRL-C to abort the program, since it will also be caught. Use at least `except Exception`, which all normal exceptions inherit from (but not some special exceptions like pressing CTRL-C).

In general it is usually not the best idea to have a lot of string addition. You could use `format` instead in `repo_formatter`:

```
def repo_formatter(scheme):
    base_url = scheme['github_repo']['address'].replace('github.com', 'raw.githubusercontent.com')
    return '{}/master/colors/{}.vim'.format(base_url, scheme['name'])
```

You have some very obvious comments in your code, especially in `download`. Comments should explain why you do something and not what. The latter should be obvious from your code! And in that function it is really easy to follow what happens, because you have chosen appropriate variable names :)

Comment: @Kernel.Panic Believe it or not, at some point you'll be able to read simple code *faster* than the comments explaining them. Thats why they can actually hinder readability to an experienced coder.

Comment: Graipher, Did you mean "string *concatenation*" instead of "string addition"?

Comment: @jpaugh Well yes and no. It is more like addition in python, because they are immutable. You don't add the second string to the end, you generate a new string which has both contents of the two strings you are adding...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I tend to think of concatenation as being a pure operation as well.

Answer (score 8):

Nice script! A few points on top of what @Graipher already pointed out.

#### Passing url parameters to requests

This is a hacky way to pass query parameters:

> ```
> url = "http://vimcolors.com/?page="
> # ...
> page_source = requests.get(url + str(page + 1))
> ```

The proper way to do this is to pass the parameters in a dictionary:

```
url = "http://vimcolors.com"
# ...
page_source = requests.get(url, {'page': page + 1})
```

#### Building path strings

This is a hacky, non-portable way to build and work with path strings:

> ```
> download_dir = 'colors/'
> # ...
>
> if os.path.isfile(download_dir + name):
>     # ...
> ```

The proper way to do this is using `os.path.join`:

```
download_dir = 'colors'
# ...

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(download_dir, name)):
    # ...
```

#### Don't repeat yourself

You wrote `self.download_dir + name` multiple times within the same scope.
Don't repeat yourself, put it into a variable and reuse it.

#### Exception handling

There are several problems with this block of code:

> ```
> try:
>     # Get the response
>     response = requests.get(url)
>     # If response is 404 (Not Found), just exit
>     if response.status_code == 404:
>         raise Exception('File not found')
>     # Create the file
>     with open(self.download_dir + name, 'wb') as file_path:
>         # Write content to the file
>         file_path.write(response.content)
>         # Confirm the download
>         print('Downloaded', name)
> except:
>     # This is a very generic error, perhaps I'll change it sometime :)
>     print('Could not download the file', name)
>     pass
> ```

@Graipher already mentioned to not use generic exceptions.
The [coding style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has many things to say about exceptions,
I suggest to read it well.

The message you print in `except` may be misleading.
As the `try` block includes not only the downloading,
but also the writing to the file,
if the latter raises an exception,
it will be caught, and the message printed will be misleading,
which can be extremely frustrating when trying to debug the problem.
At the minimum,
the `try` block should be split.

Finally,
as this block of code is at the end of the function,
the `pass` is pointless.

Comment: Didn't know those non-hacky / proper methods! Thank you, sir! :)

I will definitely update my code accordingly later on.

Comment: I was actually trying to catch a message from exception. I guess Python doesn't have anything like that? For example, in `PHP` I would do `$e->getMessage()` to fetch the proper message from exception. I couldn't find a similar solution in Python..

Comment: @Kernel.Panic http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1788/exceptions#t=201608301900261741121  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483429/how-to-print-an-error-in-python c: